# Why many servers change its uid and gid,what's the benefit?

Tags: c, security, unix

I see such logic in many open source projects:

```
if (setuid() == 0) {
   if (setgid(ccf->group) == -1) {
   ...
   if (initgroups(ccf->username, ccf->group) == -1) {
```

I have 2 questions on this:

1. What's the benifit to change to another gid and uid?
2. And what's `initgroups` for? IMO,to change gid and uid,`setuid()` and `setgid()` will be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, system daemons are spawned by init scripts and therefore run as `root`. Calling `setuid()` and `setgid()` allows them to drop their superuser privileges and impersonate another user on the system (generally far less powerful than `root`). That way, bugs and security holes become less lethal to the system.

Concerning the second part of your question, [initgroups()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/initgroups) is called to reinitialize the group access list and add `ccf->group` to the list of groups that `ccf->username` belongs to. That's probably done because calling `setgid()` is not sufficient for the access rights associated with the new group to be propagated to the process.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi,what about `initgroups`,why is it necessary here?

Comment: @cpuer, probably to set the user as a member of the group if that's not already the case. See my updated answer.

Comment: @cpuer, the code in your question does not look like it's doing that, though :)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi ,I just fixed the indentation:) Is there anywhere I can check the list of groups a specific user belongs to?

Comment: @cpuer, answer updated accordingly. Also, you can use `getgroups()` to get the groups the currently effective user belongs to.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi ,I like this accordingly change:)

Comment: initgroups set the auxiliary groups... changing the whole list ... setgid just sets to one group id.   Calling initgroups is important for systems where users are members of multiple groups, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you need administrative permission to listen on ports 1023 and below. (There are other reasons to start as administrator, but that's the big one.) But here's the thing: You can start as administrator, bind the socket, then drop down to be a user.

Now, why would you want to be a user? Well, if you run with the smallest amount of permissions possible, and your program is compromised, then the damage will be contained.

Answer (score 0):

On some OS `setgid()` toasts the supplementary groups. Calling `initgroups()` *before* `setgid()` is thus ineffective.